# installing paypal braintree to my restaurant app in android studio with kotlin language

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, paypal, sdk, braintree

i have problem installing paypal in my app in android studio with kotlin language. it would be great if there is a template with its sdk in github that i can add it to my app and there i can edit it. i will provide the code that i tried so far, but i still have problems with sdk,...

Is there anyway i can have a template that i can download from github for this issue then i customize it! or where is the place that i can start step by step regardning paypal in android studio with kotlin language?! i tried paypal and braintree documentaion! i didnot succeed.

````
package com.example.orderapp.ui

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.braintreepayments.api.DropInRequest
import com.braintreepayments.api.DropInResult
import com.example.orderapp.R
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore



class PaymentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "PaymentActivity"
    private val REQUEST_CODE = 101
    private lateinit var clientToken: String


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment)

        val paymentButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.paymentButton)
        paymentButton.setOnClickListener {
            startBraintreeDropIn()
        }

        getClientToken()
    }

    private fun getClientToken() {
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("braintree").document("clientToken")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    clientToken = document.getString("token") ?: ""
                    if (clientToken.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No client token found")
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
            }
    }

    private fun startBraintreeDropIn() {
        if (clientToken.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Client token not ready yet")
            return
        }

        val dropInRequest = DropInRequest()
            .clientToken(clientToken)
        startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val result = data?.getParcelableExtra<DropInResult>(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT)
                val paymentMethodNonce = result?.paymentMethodNonce?.nonce
                // Send strNonce to your server to create a transaction
                // Show successful toast or handle other UI changes
                Toast.makeText(this, "Payment successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish() // Finish the PaymentActivity and return to the previous screen
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled payment, handle accordingly
            } else {
                // An error occurred, handle it and log it
                val error = data?.getIntExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_ERROR, 0)
                Log.e(TAG, "Error during payment: $error")
            }
        }
    }
}
``` .these are the errors so far : Unresolved reference: clientToken. Unresolved reference: nonce.
````